# How to override "acts_as" methods from inherited classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, methods, overriding

I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and Ruby on Rails 3.2.2. I have following statements:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_something :arg1A, :arg2A, :argNA
end

class B < A
  acts_as_something :arg1B, :arg2B, :argNB
end
```

On inheriting (`B < A`) it seems that the method `acts_as_something` stated in `A` is *not* overridden by the method`acts_as_something` stated in `B`: when I inspect arguments related to the `acts_as_something` method for the `B` class, those still refer to `:arg1A`, `:arg2A`, `:argNA` (*not* to `:arg1B`, `:arg2B`, `:argNB`).

What could have happened? How to properly override the `acts_as_something` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `acts_as_something :arg1A, :arg2A, :argNA` lines are not method definitions but invocations of class methods within the scope of the class. Therefore you cannot override them.

However, depending on the implementation of the "acts_as" methods you can override the effect that they have in a subclass. But this completely depends on what the "acts_as" method in question does...

Comment: You can think of the `acts_as` method present in the question as the `acts_as_list` method provided by the [ActAsList](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list) gem.